# I'm kinda new to React Js and I keep getting "Type Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'buttonText')"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I couldn't find a solution yet and i'm stuck.
When I click the button "add to cart" it should change the text to "adding to cart..." but Instead i'm getting that error.

I'm not getting why is undefined if Im waiting until I get all the data from the fetch.

I'm getting this object after fetching:

```
{
    "products":[
       {  "id":0,  
          "name":"doughnut choco",
          "price":25,
          "desc":"Doughnut salado relleno de Kimchi casero y queso crema vegano",
          "img":"https://delishvegan.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/brunch2-300x300.png",
          "units":100,
          "buttonText":"add to cart"
          
       },
}
```

Here's my code:

`````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../sass/layout/_grid.scss";
import "../sass/components/_product-card.scss";
import "../sass/components/_buttons.scss";

export interface ProductProps {
    products: {
        id: number;
        name: string;
        price: number;
        desc: string;
        img: string;
        units: number;
        buttonText: string;
    }[];
}

const ProductCard: React.FC<ProductProps> = (props) => {
    /* const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); */
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState(props.products);

    const handleClick = (index: number) => {
        const newText = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buttonText));
        const testing = newText || [];
        testing[index].buttonText = "Adding to cart...";
        setButtonText(newText);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setButtonText(props.products);
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(buttonText)));
        }, 2000);
    };

    return (
        <>
            {props.products.length > 0 &&
                props.products.map((it, index) => (
                    <article key={it.id} className="product-card">
                        <img src={it.img} alt={it.name} />
                        <h3>{it.name}</h3>
                        <p>{it.desc}</p>
                        <h4>{it.price}.00€</h4>
                        <div className="product-card__button--wrapper">
                            <button
                                className="product-card-button"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    handleClick(index);
                                    console.log(it.id);
                                }}
                                key={it.id}
                            >
                                {it.buttonText}
                            </button>
                            <button className="product-card-button">info</button>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default ProductCard;
````Thanks!!!
`````

Comment: what is your props.products type? Because to me it seems an array of objects. So it seems like you are setting your state variable `buttonText` to an array of objects rather than a string which I assume is one of the properties of one of the objects in the array

Comment: Ok, so know I changed it to string and It works. The only problem is that the setTimeout function doesn't work maybe I should parse it. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the following line of code :

```
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState<string>(props.products?.buttonText);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).